# Obtain Users and Groups from Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, terminal

How would I obtain the Users and Groups listed under System Preferences from a Mac through the terminal?

I've tried

```
dscl . list /users
dscl . list /groups
```

But they give me a list of system-ish users as well. I just want the users and groups I would see if I went into System Preferences and viewed them.

Comment: Hey there--this is probably better-suited to superuser, another stack exchange site.

Answer (score 2):

The system treats users/groups with IDs `<= 500` as "system" users, which are hidden from the UI. So you can do this:

```
$ for user in `dscl . list /users`; do if [ `dscl . read "/users/$user" | grep UniqueID | awk '{print $2;}'` -gt 500 ]; then echo "$user" ;fi; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dscacheutil` to get those lists.

```
dscacheutil -q user
dscacheutil -q group
```